# git: rebase two branches that are interconnected with merge commits

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have a history like:

```
 A - B - C - D - E                       [master]
         |\ 
         |  I - J - m1 - K - L - m2 - O  [topic-a]
          \       /             /
            P - R - S ------- T - U      [topic-b]
```

i.e. topic-b is periodically merged into topic-a.

Now I want to rebase both topic-a and topic-B branches onto the new master (`E`), while also preserving merge commits (but preferably without the need to manually reapply them like the `git rebase --rebase-merges` seems to require, especially that in my case the rebase does not change the merged files, so the exact same merge result could be automatically taken), so that I can continue my workflow (merging topic-b into topic-a) with the access to all previous merges. So, the expected result is:

```
A - B - C - D - E                       [master]
                |\ 
                |  I' - J' - m1' - K' - L' - m2' - O'  [topic-a]
                 \         /                /
                   P' -  R' - S' -------- T' - U'      [topic-b]
```

The next step for me is to rebase not onto `master` but onto a completely disjoint `master-2` branch, which I'd normally do with `rebase --onto`.

I have looked at most of the basic git commands, including rebase (with options like `--rebase-merges`), merge, cherry-pick, apply and am, but none of them or their combination seems to provide the solution.

Comment: "while also preserving merge commits (but without the need to reapply them like the git rebase --rebase-merges seems to require)". How are you imagining that would be possible? If you don't know how to do it, how can you stipulate that the obviously right answer is not the answer? Of _course_ you would need to reapply them. As your own diagram shows, these would _all_ be new commits, including the merge commits. That's the _only_ possible way.

Comment: @matt `git rebase --rebase-merges` probably requires manually reapplying merges because only the target commit is different, but here, if all 3 commits would somehow be rebased (especially, as in my case, when the rebase does not change any involved file), then I think applying the same merge automatically could be possible. I may make it more clear though.
Otherwise, what is the obviously right answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `git rebase --rebase-merges` requiring "manually reapplying merges", and suspect that's also what matt's comment is confused by. Do you mean that the rebase stops and waits for you to do something like resolve conflicts? This appears to be exactly the scenario that [the manual describes as the use case for that option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_rebasing_merges).

Comment: Yes, I have to re-resolve all the conflicts that were resolved in the original merge commits, even though the files have not changed with the rebase, so the commits resolution could be otherwise re-taken. I don't quite see that point being discussed in the provided manual, while also it is not the main purpose of  --rebase-merges. Anyway, it OP the situation is quite different and that topic may not even apply in the same form (I don't know how to even start with the rebase), so please treat it as a secondary consideration.

Comment: Side thought: if you know in advance you're going to rebase both branches like this, perhaps merging one into the other isn't the best choice. (Even more so if you have merge conflicts during those merges.) For example, if every time you would merge `b` into `a`, if you rebased `a` onto `b` instead, then you'd be in a situation where you can simply rebase `a` onto the latest `master` using the `--update-refs` option which would  effectively rebase both `a` and `b` in one shot.

Comment: The only difference I see between your example and the one in the manual is that you currently have two branch tips which you want to rebase. That would be easy to solve, though: make one last merge from topic-b into topic-a, rebase topic-a preserving merges, then point topic-b at the relevant commit in the rebased history. Auto-resolving conflicts is trickier, though, because git doesn't really store enough information.

Comment: Note that `git rerere` can help with repeated merge conflicts. It's not a panacea, of course.

Comment: @mcpiroman Do you have to keep the history with the merges? Couldn't you linearize the history while rebasing to get rid of all the merge commits? You are already rewriting history, so why not simplify it at the same time?

Comment: Yes @knittl, having those two branches, including merges, is an important part of my workflow.